# I am trying to rename a bunch of files in a directory but I am getting an error("NameError: name 'root' is not defined") when saving renamed files

Tags: python-2.7

`htnl_files` is my directory and I have to remove `"https:@@www.wisdomjobs.com@e-university@"` part from the every file of my directory and I need to save files to same directory.

```
import os
file_names=os.listdir('html_files')
for file_name in file_names:
  #print file_name
  file_name = file_name.replace("https:@@www.wisdomjobs.com@e-university@","")
  #print filename   
  fullpath = os.path.join(root/html_files, file_name)
  os.rename(fullpath, file_name)
```

Comment: please someone help me with this

Comment: what is `root`? what is `html_files` (the variable, not the string). `/` will only work this way if `root` is a `pathlib.Path` object. is it?

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: i need to save my files to "html_files" directory

Comment: NameError: name 'root' is not defined this is my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neither `root` nor `html_files` are defined in your code. what you probably want is this:

```
import os
file_names = os.listdir('html_files')
for orig_name in file_names:
    new_name = orig_name.replace("https:@@www.wisdomjobs.com@e-university@", "")
    orig_path = os.path.join('html_files', orig_name)
    new_path = os.path.join('html_files', new_name)
    os.rename(orig_path, new_path)
```

Comment: sure i will edit my question.and thanks for your answer its worked.